# broadcast packets sent from tap interface not received

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tun

I am making a program similar to simpletun [from here](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/).

1. an application sends out UDP broadcasts to the tap interface.
2. program listening on the tap interface (similar to simpletun)receives the packet and echoes it again as broadcast.
3. I am able to see both the packets on wireshark but the application does not receive it. seems that the kernel is dropping them.
4. If similar packets are sent from a different machine . it works fine.

tun/tap code:-

```
char datagram[4096];
struct pseudo_header
{
        u_int32_t source_address;
        u_int32_t dest_address;
        u_int8_t placeholder;
        u_int8_t protocol;
        u_int16_t udp_length;
};
struct pseudo_header psh;
char *pseudogram;

 nread = cread(tap_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);

    memcpy(&source_port,(char *)(buffer+14+20),2);  

    memset (datagram, 0, 4096);

    memcpy(datagram,buffer,14); //copy eth-header
    datagram[6] = 0xXX;//change mac address
    datagram[7] = 0xXX;
    datagram[8] = 0xXX;
    //IP header
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (datagram +14);
    //TCP header
    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) (datagram + 14 + sizeof (struct iphdr));

    data = datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr) +14;     
    strcpy(data,"Any string");
    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->tot_len = sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
    iph->id = htonl (54321);        //Id of this packet
    iph->frag_off = 0;
    iph->ttl = 255;

    iph->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    iph->check = 0;         //Set to 0 before calculating checksum

    strcpy(source_ip , "192.168.0.99");
    iph->saddr = inet_addr ( source_ip );   //Spoof the source ip address
    strcpy(destination_ip , "255.255.255.255");
    iph->daddr = inet_addr (destination_ip);


     udph->source = htons(5933);
    //udph->dest = htons(source_port);
    udph->dest = (source_port);
    udph->len = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));


    //Now the UDP checksum
    psh.source_address = inet_addr( source_ip );
    psh.dest_address = inet_addr(destination_ip);
    psh.placeholder = 0;
    psh.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    psh.udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data) );

    int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
    pseudogram = malloc(psize);

    memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , udph , sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct udphdr), data , strlen(data));

    udph->check = 0;
    udph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) pseudogram , psize);
    //Ip checksum
    iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len);

    //writeback
    cwrite(tap_fd,datagram,iph->tot_len +14);
```

The above code when run from another machine  using raw sockets read and write works well. (without eth-header).

Receiving Application code:-

```
int broadcast =1;

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
      err("socket");

setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BINDTODEVICE,"tun0",5);

bzero(&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
memset(&my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,255,sizeof(my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr));

ret = setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&broadcast,sizeof(broadcast));
    if(ret<0)
      printf("setsockopt bindto failed");

    if (sendto(sockfd,buf,500,0, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr,slen_len) == -1)
        err("send()");

    recvfrom(sockfd, buf, 500, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &slen);
```

Comment: Where you call setsockopt with SO_BROADCAST - what is the type and initialized value of the "broadcast" variable?

Comment: broadcast is set to 1. added only the relevant parts of code.`int broadcast = 1;`

Comment: That should be correct then. It was just a hunch.

Comment: hey thanks for supporting me and pushing me to correctit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using proper checksum and proper byte order for tot_len for ip header

`iph->tot_len = (htons)sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct udphdr) + strlen(data);`

`iph->id = htons (54321);        //Id of this packet`

`iph->check = htons(csum ((unsigned short *) datagram,sizeof(struct ip_hdr)));`
**where csum is  a common function to calculate checksum.

from a different machine packet was received because kernel's network stack was recalculating iph->tot_len and the ip checksum. so the packet was properly formed.

with my tun interface after correcting the checksum and byteorder of tot_len  packet was received by the application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the host firewall rules  ?

Comment: firewall is disabled `service ufw stop`

Comment: Then maybe you don't have the good rights to use RAW sockets on that particular computer.
Windows, for example, doesn't allow you to create a full raw socket.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark guess:

But you could try changing your TUN/TAP code be setting the destination **MAC** address to broadcast (FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF) when it sees the IP destination as the broadcast IP (255.255.255.255)?

Comment: dest mac and dest ip in both packets to and from tun/tap interface are broadcast only. what I am changing in this line `datagram[6] = 0xXX;//change mac address` is only the source mac when echoing the packet back